# simple nuclear $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Does there exist an infinite dimensional simple nuclear $C^*$ algebra which admits a tracial state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, many. A prominent example is the CAR-algebra. Another example is the Jiang-Su algebra which is not a UHF-algebra.

Comment: This is also no obstruction. For example the Jacelon-Razak algebra is an example, see https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.5397. I am sure there are more basic examples.